# interop scala with java Getting but Java-defined trait List is invariant in type E

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to return inherited java type from scala and I am getting 
... Java-defined trait List is invariant in type E

**Java code :**

```
public interface Foo {
....
}
public class Bar implements Foo {
....
}
public interface FooReader {
  List<Foo> getFoos() throws Exception;
}
```

**Scala Code:**

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
class Buz extends FooReader {
def getFoos: util.List[Foo] = {
val foos = List(new Bar).asjava
foos
}
}
```

this doesn't compile :

> [ERROR] Note: Bar <: Foo, but Java-defined trait List is invariant in
>   type E.

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Foo is a subtype of Bar, you don't even need to type cast, you can simply tell list you're passing Foo as Bar:

val foos = List(new Bar: Foo).asJava

If you're not initalizing your list inline, since the immutable scala list is covariant in its type parameter, you can do:

val foos = (listOfBars: List[Foo]).asJava

Answer (score 1):

Type `java.util.List` is Invariant. Signature,

```
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E>
```

You could make it working by type casting,

```
val foos = List(new Bar().asInstanceOf[Foo]).asJava
```

or

```
val foos = List(new Bar(x=2)).asJava.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[Foo]]
```