# How to convert objects from scala to java correctly?

Tags: java, scala, quartz-scheduler

We develop in Scala and in our app we use Quartz as a scheduler.

Currently working on a function that schedules things in bulk and I am running into an issue converting scala map into java so Quartz will accept it.

The function looks like this:

```
private def rescheduleJobs(infos: List[TaskDueNotificationInfo]): Unit = {

    val jobDatas = infos.foldLeft(List.empty[TaskDueNotificationJobData]) { (datas, info) =>
      val taskIdStr = info.task.id.uuid.toString

      val triggerKey = new TriggerKey(taskIdStr, Group.TaskDueNotification.toString)
      val jobKey = new JobKey(taskIdStr, Group.TaskDueNotification.toString)
      val jobDetail =
        newJob(classOf[TaskDueNotificationJob]).withIdentity(jobKey).usingJobData("taskId", taskIdStr).build()

      val sysTz = DateTimeZone.getDefault
      val sysStartTime = info.task.dueDate match {
        case Some(dueDate) => new DateTime(dueDate, info.timeZone).toDateTime(sysTz)
        case None          => throw UnexpectedException("no due date set")
      }

      val triggerBuilder = newTrigger().withIdentity(triggerKey).forJob(jobKey).startAt(sysStartTime.toDate)
      val trigger = triggerBuilder.build()

      datas :+ TaskDueNotificationJobData(jobDetail, trigger)
    }

    val jobsMap = jobDatas.map(data => data.jobDetail -> Set(data.trigger).asJava).toMap.asJava

    Try {

      jobScheduler.scheduler.scheduleJobs(jobsMap, true)

    } match {

      case Success(_) => // All good

      case Failure(e) => logger.error(e.getMessage)

    }
  }
```

When we scheduling one by one with `Date scheduleJob(JobDetail jobDetail, Trigger trigger)` then we initially create java objects and everything works fine.
In the code above I am getting a the following error:

```
[error] /Users/ShurikAg/ProcessStreet/dev/process-street/app/scheduling/schedulers/TaskDueNotificationScheduler.scala:99: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : java.util.Map[org.quartz.JobDetail,java.util.Set[org.quartz.Trigger]]
[error]  required: java.util.Map[org.quartz.JobDetail,java.util.Set[_ <: org.quartz.Trigger]]
[error] Note: java.util.Set[org.quartz.Trigger] <: java.util.Set[_ <: org.quartz.Trigger], but Java-defined trait Map is invariant in type V.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: java.util.Set[_ <: org.quartz.Trigger]`. (SLS 3.2.10)
[error]       jobScheduler.scheduler.scheduleJobs(jobsMap, true)
```

If I cast it to SimpleTrigger (which it is) like so:

```
val jobsMap =
      jobDatas.map(data => data.jobDetail -> Set(data.trigger.asInstanceOf[SimpleTrigger]).asJava).toMap.asJava
```

The error is the same:

```
[error] /Users/ShurikAg/ProcessStreet/dev/process-street/app/scheduling/schedulers/TaskDueNotificationScheduler.scala:100: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : java.util.Map[org.quartz.JobDetail,java.util.Set[org.quartz.SimpleTrigger]]
[error]  required: java.util.Map[org.quartz.JobDetail,java.util.Set[_ <: org.quartz.Trigger]]
[error] Note: java.util.Set[org.quartz.SimpleTrigger] <: java.util.Set[_ <: org.quartz.Trigger], but Java-defined trait Map is invariant in type V.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: java.util.Set[_ <: org.quartz.Trigger]`. (SLS 3.2.10)
[error]       jobScheduler.scheduler.scheduleJobs(jobsMap, true)
```

However, `SimpleTrigger` is extending from `Trigger`.

Even if I am defining the types for Set and Map like this:

```
val jobsMap =
      jobDatas
        .map(data => data.jobDetail -> Set[SimpleTrigger](data.trigger.asInstanceOf[SimpleTrigger]).asJava)
        .toMap[JobDetail, java.util.Set[SimpleTrigger]]
        .asJava
```

It does not help.

What is the correct way to do this kind of conversion?

Answer (score 1):

A slightly better alternative to your answer, but otherwise it's the most reasonable thing to do:

```
jobDatas
  .map(data => data.jobDetail -> (Set(data.trigger).asJava: java.util.Set[T] forSome { type T <: Trigger }))
  .toMap
  .asJava
```

It uses type ascription instead of a cast, so it's safer in case you change the code later (a type ascription won't compile if it's incorrect, a cast will); and this ascription has a simpler type and more narrow scope.

Comment: Getting this error: `Cannot prove that (org.quartz.JobDetail, java.util.Set[_$1]) forSome { type _$1 <: org.quartz.Trigger } <:< (T, U).
.toMap
[error]        ^`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found A way to do it; just not sure if that is the best one.

The only way it worked (following this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/33594711/1293827) is:

```
val jobsMap =
      jobDatas
        .map(data => data.jobDetail -> Set(data.trigger).asJava)
        .toMap
        .asJava
        .asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[JobDetail, java.util.Set[_ <: Trigger]]]
```